# Update base eclipse ide

Tags: eclipse, ide

is it possible to update the eclipse base ide offline with new eclipse archive?

Considering eclipse 4.3.1 with a lot of plugins and features, now I downloaded the eclipse 4.3.2 package and want to update the base ide offline and keep the old one plugins, features, and everything...
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is easier just to do `Help > Check for Updates` in you existing 4.3.1 it should find the 4.3.2 and do to update for you. Just done that here this morning!

Comment: @greg-449 thanks dude, so you say I cannot update the current one with the new one I just downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you cannot update the base install offline..check for updates will update the base install online keeping the 3rd party plugins